# Specs not running as "sandbox" creating dynamic Classes

Tags: ruby, rspec, metaprogramming, ruby-2.0

I have a module with a `define` method that creates a class dynamically like this:

```
require "active_support/all"

class SomeBaseClass
  # code
end

module MyModule
  def self.define(_class_name)
    class_name = _class_name.classify
    Object.const_set(class_name, Class.new(SomeBaseClass))
  end
end
```

Then, if I do: `MyModule.define(:my_class)` I will get: `MyClass`

My spec:

```
describe "#define" do
  it "creates a dynamic class" do
    MyModule.define("my_class")
    expect(subject.const_defined?("MyClass")).to be_truthy
  end
end
```

This works beautifully... But! when I create a **new spec** defining `MyClass` I get this warning: `warning: already initialized constant MyClass`

This is happening because I've been created `MyClass` in the previous spec. So, the question is: **How can I avoid this?** I want "a fresh start" on each spec.

**UPDATE: solution based on @giglemad answer...**

```
before do
  Object.send(:remove_const, :MyClass) if Object.const_defined?("MyClass")
end

describe "#define" do
  it "creates a dynamic class" do
    MyModule.define("my_class")
    expect(subject.const_defined?("MyClass")).to be_truthy
  end
end
```

Comment: rspec has `stub_const` which allows you to define constants (like classes) and automatically cleans them up after the test [docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-11/docs/stubbing-constants)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a different class name every time based on the name + some convention. I use timestamps to do so.

```
def nano_timestamp_string
  Time.now.to_f.to_s.sub('.','')
end
```

You can pretty much reuse that convention any time you need something unique but still want to write your tests the same way. I use it for unique emails for instance. If you still want to def and then undef a constant with the same name then you might want to use

```
Object.send(:remove_const,:Myconst)
```

Comment: I think option 2 is more clean.